# PDO Connection: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, database, class, pdo

Hello i have a question PDO connection. My conn.php is

```
<?php
define('host', 'localhost');
define('host_user', 'root');
define('host_pass', '');
define('host_db', 'testdb');
class Database {
public $conn;
public function Connect() {
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . host . ";dbname=" . host_db, host_user, host_pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Connection error:" . $e->getMessage();
}
}
}
?>
```

When i use this

```
$dbClass = new Database();
$stmt = $dbClass::Connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posts");
```

it returns following **error:**

> Call to a member function prepare() on null

Why is it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because `prepare()` is a function of `PDO`, but since `Connect()` doesn't return anything, you're calling `prepare()` on nothing.

You hsould modify `Connect()` so that it returns the PDO object. Add this at the end of the function (or the end of the `Try` block):

```
return $conn;
```

Comment: Thanks it works!!!

Comment: @user3227899 You're welcome:-) Remember to select my answer if it helped you solve the issue.

Comment: select? what is mean?